# Create a list of pointers to random generated int

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having some difficulty in generating a random `int*` and store it into a `list<int*>`.

I have tried the following:

```
std::list<int*> generateInt(){
   std::list<int*> randomInt;

   int i = 0;

   // initialize random seed
   srand (time(NULL));

   while (i < 5){
      int* random = (int*)std::rand();
      std::cout << "Random int generated: " << random << std::endl;

      randomInt.push_back(random);
      i++;
   }

   return randomInt;
}
```

But I get compiler issue as following

```
error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
       int* random = (int*)std::rand();
                                     ^
```

I'm not sure if i'm missing something important here?
Any help or advice would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using pointers?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you really want pointers to random locations in memory?

Comment: `int* random = (int*)std::rand();` is complete nonsense.

Comment: And you should be calling srand() _once_, at the start of your program.

Comment: I'm implementing an assignment question that requires to store a list of pointers to random integers. Is this the right approach? I thought I needed a function that returns a list of random generated int pointers.

Comment: @ChanbothSom Also `srand (time(NULL));` should be called just once per process.

Comment: `srand (time(NULL));` is not in the loop so wouldn't it only be called just once?

Comment: @ChanbothSom Depends on how your function is called.

Comment: Any advice to get around the issue right now? Maybe just ditch the whole idea of `list<int*>`?

Comment: @ChanbothSom _"Maybe just ditch the whole idea of `list<int*>`?"_ That would be a great step forward.

Comment: See random number generator example in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: If you want repeatable pseudo-random sequences (e.g. for a unit test) use the same non-random seed.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of is:

```
std::vector<int> generateInt(){
   std::vector<int> randomInt;

   int i = 0;

   // initialize random seed
   // srand (time(NULL)); Let that be the first line in main()

   while (i < 5){
      int random = std::rand();
      std::cout << "Random int generated: " << random << std::endl;

      randomInt.push_back(random);
      i++;
   }

   return randomInt;
}
```

There's no need to introduce pointers or `std::list` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pointers in your task, list use a self allocator:) if you need poiner use unique ore shared ptr
if you need int prt with random value use

```
int* p = new int{rand()};
```

Use mt to generate a random value (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/) ande see coments in code block

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <random>
#include <functional>


namespace test {
    std::list<int*> __attribute__((noinline))
    foo() noexcept{
        // Mersenne Twister generator with random device seed
        // good way and not use time spec
        std::mt19937_64 generator(std::random_device{}());
        // for int gen
        // this a seporator for generated value
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> uid(0, 256);
        // make functional object to use
        auto rand_gen{std::bind(uid, generator)};

        std::list<int*> lst;
        int i{0};
        for (auto i{0}; i < 5; ++i) {
            // emplase is right way now
            try {
                lst.emplace_back(new int{rand_gen()});
            } catch (std::bad_alloc& ba) {
                std::cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << std::endl;
            }
        }
        return std::move(lst);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::list<int*> lst{test::foo()};
    for(const auto& val : lst) {
        std::cout << *val << std::endl;
        delete val;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ore use /dev/urandom if you linux like user :)

Comment: Lot of stuff in here you'll need to unpack for the asker. I strongly recommend explaining what this code is doing and why. Currently you have what's called a Code-Only Answer, and they are usually good for little more than leveling up the asker's copy-paste skills.

Comment: In C++11 you should use lambdas instead of `std::bind`. And that actually is unnecessary here.

Comment: in 2019 use  a C++11 - bad way

Comment: But the stated requirement was create a list of pointers to random ints, not a list of random ints. Telling the instructor the assignment is wrong is unlikely to be fruitful.

Comment: i fix this now ;)

Comment: for `int* p = new int{rand()};` it seems to be working really well for me at the moment, but I'm only noticing positive int?

Comment: you can use  uid : std::uniform_int_distribution<> uid(-127, 127) ore all what you want;

Comment: any reason for -127,127 in particular?

Comment: was I supposed to be using

Comment: `std::list<int*>attribute`

Comment: because you wrote it as no inline, I don't quite understand that line, sorry

Answer (score 0):

A note: You would not do this in real life. You would use a container of `int`, possibly `std::list` but more likely `std::vector`, not pointers to `int`. This is probably an assignment to make the learner struggle for a while with pointers.

So let's deal in pointers and do this the hard way.

```
int* random = (int*)std::rand();
```

means *Get me a random number and store the random number as a memory address.* What does this address point to? Anybody's guess. It's random. That makes it a bad idea.

A pointer must point to a valid object of the same type (or has an [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) with the pointer's type) or it should be pointed at a "safe" parking location like `nullptr` until it can be pointed at a valid object. There are exceptions to this, but you'll learn those later.

Given

> I'm implementing an assignment question that requires to store a list of pointers to random integers.

```
std::list<int*> randomInt;
```

Is probably correct. But... You still need an `int` to point at, so

1. Get a valid integer,
2. store the random number as an integer in that integer, and
3. store a pointer to that integer in the `list`.

So how do you get a valid integer? Obviously you need more than one so,

```
int number; // easy, but not enough numbers.
```

is out. All of `randomInt` would point at the same place and only the last value generated would be stored.

If you don't know how many numbers you're getting you need dynamic storage and should use `new`

```
int * random = new int; // get an int from dynamic memory
*random = std::rand(); // generate random number and assign to int pointed at by random
```

(or [a smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) if they are available to you). Remember everything you `new` you will have to `delete`

```
for (int * p:randomInt) // for all pointers in randomInt
{
    delete p; // free the memory (and other stuff you'll cover later)
}
```

after you are finished using it to avoid memory leaks. This is disturbingly error-prone, it is sickeningly easy to have a path that misses the `delete` or `delete`s while the allocation is still needed, so avoid this in real life. Use Automatic allocation, containers and smart pointers. If you can't, embrace the power of [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii).

Where possible avoid having to mess around with managing dynamic memory, smart pointer managed or otherwise, because dynamic memory always has a cost.

In this case it looks like a maximum of five, so you can make an array

```
int numbers[5];
```

(but NOT a local variable

```
std::list<int*> generateInt(){
    int numbers[5]; // do not use!!! FATAL!!!
```

as it would go out of scope and vanish at the end of the function, leaving the program with a `list` full of pointers to invalid objects) and point at the elements of the array. For a simple program, you could get away with a `static` local variable

```
std::list<int*> generateInt(){
    static int numbers[5];
```

or a global variable

```
int numbers[5];
std::list<int*> generateInt(){
```

but what if the function is called more than once? The second call would destroy the results of the first call. This may be tolerable, but the responsibility for making this call and guaranteeing the program works as expected falls on the programmer.

My suspicion is the Asker is intended to use `new`. Check with whomever assigned the problem to see what other options they will accept.

Comment: thank you so much for the thorough explanation. I will check with the assignment specs and marker asap. as for now, I have some other issues such as 0xfffffffff and things like that when I try to allocate the pointers to those ints I generated. Any advice? if I allocate by say some big amount less, then it'd back down less than fffffff but if I then allocate more big int, it'd go back to that

Comment: Typically (but not always. [See the first table here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)) `int` can only hold a 32 bit signed number for a maximum of about 2 billion (or 0x7fffffff). If you need a larger number, you need too use a different type. an `unsigned int` will (probably) store 0xffffffff, but no more. `long` or `long long` may store 64 bits. In addition, the range of numbers provided by `std::rand` may be as small as 0 to 32767. For larger numbers use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: Side note: [Some interesting viewing](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) on `rand` and its modern replacements. Quite funny, too.